# C Pointers Example - What is so bad about this?

Tags: c, pointers

In our lecture we had the following example:

```
int *foo(int x) {
    return &x;
}

int* pt = foo(x);
*pt = 17;
```

It was shown as a bad example, but not further explained. Why is this bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
int *foo(int x) {
```

`x` is a local, non-static variable. By doing

```
return &x;
```

you return the address of the local variable `x`. It exists as long as the function does , and when the function exits, this address will be invalid for you to play with. By using

```
*pt = 17;
```

you dereference this address and write `17` to this invalid memory location. This triggers [Undefined Behavior](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This is why the given code is bad.

Answer (score 5):

Bad thing is that you are returning a pointer to an automatic local variable. It will no longer be exist once function returns and then the statement `*pt = 17;` will cause program to behave erratically.

A pointer to `static` local variable can be returned.

```
int *foo() {
    static int x;
    return &x;
}
int* pt = foo();
*pt = 17;
```

Answer (score 4):

In `foo` the variable `x` is local hence it ceases to exist after the method exits.  When a function returns, its automatic, local variables are discarded, so the returned pointer in this case is invalid (it points to an array that no longer exists).

```
int* pt = foo(x);
*pt = 17;
```

Hence, now access to `pt` results in [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should `malloc` it instead:

```
int *foo() 
{
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = 0;
    return x;
}

int* pt = foo();
*pt = 17;
free(pt);
```